# How can I define this numeric operator generalization?

Tags: haskell

I'm making a simple expression evaluator. Here are the types:

```hs
data Value = IntV Integer | FloatV Float | BoolV Bool
```

Here is how I defined addition (I know the function is partial, but it doesn't matter in this case):

```hs
addValues :: Value -> Value -> Value
addValues (IntV n) (FloatV f) = FloatV (fromIntegral n + f)
addValues (FloatV f) (IntV n) = FloatV (fromIntegral n + f)
addValues (FloatV f1) (FloatV f2) = FloatV (f1 + f2)
addValues (IntV n1) (IntV n2) = IntV (n1 + n2)
```

Integer values are converted to floats if they are operated with another float. If not, they remain as integers.

Now, here is how I defined number comparison:

```hs
isLessThan :: Value -> Value -> Value
isLessThan (IntV n) (FloatV f) = BoolV (fromIntegral n < f)
isLessThan (FloatV f) (IntV n) = BoolV (fromIntegral n < f)
isLessThan (FloatV f1) (FloatV f2) = BoolV (f1 < f2)
isLessThan (IntV n1) (IntV n2) = BoolV (n1 < n2)
```

As you can see, it starts to get repetitive. The only differences between those two functions (and many others like subtraction, multiplication, etc) are the constructor used to return the Values and the operator used between the numbers inside the Values. I tried to define a function to generalize this behavior:

```hs
numericOperation :: (c -> Value) -> (a -> b -> c) -> Value -> Value -> Value
numericOperation resFun op (IntV n) (FloatV f) = resFun $ fromIntegral n `op` f
numericOperation resFun op (FloatV f) (IntV n) = resFun $ fromIntegral n `op` f
numericOperation resFun op (FloatV f1) (FloatV f2) = resFun $ f1 `op` f2
numericOperation resFun op (IntV n1) (IntV n2) = resFun $ n1 `op` n2
```

and then I would be able to redefine the previous functions like so:

```hs
isLessThan :: Value -> Value -> Value
isLessThan v1 v2 = numericOperation BoolV (<) v1 v2
```

However, this doesn't work because the operator takes an `a` and a `b`, but in the function definition it's used as if it took an Integer and a Float, or two Floats, etc. How can I write this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to define a data type for each variety of overloaded operation, such as different arity and overloading rules. Here, you might just have a binary function with numeric input and some value as output:

```
data NumOp = NumOp
  { integral :: Integer -> Integer -> Value
  , floating :: Float -> Float -> Value
  }
```

Then your `numericOperation` type can handle the promotion and dispatch to the appropriate functions:

```
type Binary = Value -> Value -> Value

numericOperation :: NumOp -> Binary
numericOperation op (IntV n1) (IntV n2) = integral op n1 n2
numericOperation op (IntV n) (FloatV f) = floating op (fromIntegral n) f
numericOperation op (FloatV f) (IntV n) = floating op f (fromIntegral n)
numericOperation op (FloatV f1) (FloatV f2) = floating op f1 f2
```

The operations themselves can be constructed directly:

```
isLessThan :: Binary
isLessThan = numericOperation less
  where
    less = NumOp
      { integral = fmap BoolV . (<)  -- (<) @Integer
      , floating = fmap BoolV . (<)  -- (<) @Float
      }

addValues :: Binary
addValues = numericOperation add
  where
    add = NumOp
      { integral = fmap IntV . (+)    -- (+) @Integer
      , floating = fmap FloatV . (+)  -- (+) @Float
      }
```

Or as convenience wrappers using extensions like `RankNTypes`, which allows you to pass a polymorphic function as an argument:

```
{-# Language RankNTypes #-}

relationalBinaryOp
  :: (forall a. (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool) -> NumOp
relationalBinaryOp f = NumOp
  { integral = fmap BoolV . f  -- f @Integer
  , floating = fmap BoolV . f  -- f @Float
  }

numericBinaryOp
  :: (forall a. (Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> NumOp
numericBinaryOp f = NumOp
  { integral = fmap IntV . f    -- f @Integer
  , floating = fmap FloatV . f  -- f @Float
  }
```

```
isLessThan     = numericOperation $ relationalBinaryOp (<)
isGreaterThan  = numericOperation $ relationalBinaryOp (>)

addValues      = numericOperation $ numericBinaryOp (+)
subtractValues = numericOperation $ numericBinaryOp (-)

-- …
```

There are other ways of organising this, of course, such as skipping `NumOp` and passing its fields directly—whether as separate functions, or as a single polymorphic function using `RankNTypes` as above. Since your two examples have different constraints (`Num` vs. `Ord`), I’d probably separate them into `numericOperation :: (forall a. (Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> Binary` and `relationalOperation :: (forall a. (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool) -> Binary` instead of trying to abstract over the constraints.

It’s also possible to reflect more of the dynamic information into the static Haskell types using GADTs and typeclasses or type families, but that’s more involved.

Tangentially, it strikes me as a bit odd to use the arbitrary-precision `Integer` for integral values, but the compact fixed-precision 32-bit `Float` for fractional values. The conversion from `Integer` to `Float` is lossy—in fact, even `Int` (typically 64 bits) to `Double` (53 significand bits) would be lossy. If you need an arbitrary-precision fractional type, the `Ratio` type in `Data.Ratio` provides generic rational numbers, and there’s an alias `Rational` for ratios of arbitrary-precision `Integer`s.

```
> import Data.Ratio

> 0.1 + 0.2 :: Double
0.30000000000000004

> 1 % 10 + 2 % 10 :: Rational
3 % 10

> fromRational (1 % 10 + 2 % 10) :: Double
0.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really liked what you said about defining it as `numericOperation :: (forall a. (Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> Binary`. I tried it with RankNTypes enabled and it works great! About the `Float` type, I don't think I can change it to `Ratio` because I also need to do things like square roots and so on which are not always rational. Should I still change it to something else?

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco: Ah not necessarily, I don’t know your particular use case, I just thought I’d mention that rationals are available, in case they were suitable. `Double` is probably what I would choose by default, unless I have a particular reason for `Float`.

Comment: Aside, I suppose that technically it’s possible to represent exact [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) (including square roots) using their integer polynomials. E.g. √2 is a root of x² − 2, so it becomes a coefficient list `[1, 0, -2]` plus an interval to select the positive/real root. But I don’t know if there’s a library for that, and I wouldn’t do it by hand.